# page.php not displaying content

Tags: page-template, the-content

I am using a page.php template I have used on about 400 Wordpress websites, and all of a sudden the loop decides it doesn't want to display any content.

Code is:

```
<div class="text-content">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Page title displays fine so loop is fine, content remains blank.

Any advice? Never seen this before. Thanks

Comment: Couple of initial thoughts: Might be a filter, the text might be there but not visible due to CSS, there may be no content saved, or it might be a genuine issue. Your question is not focused enough. What have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: I tried disabling the 2 activated plugins, no luck, viewed the source and there is definately no content so not CSS, tried removing the title so its just content, title disappeared but still no content, finally tried deleting the content, re-publishing the page, then re-pasting content in and re-publishing again, nothing! :-(

Comment: Could you post up your content? Or try extra simple content (like 'test content') and see if that shows up? That would rule out a problem with your content.

Comment: Just replaced all content with "test" and still nothing, this is on all pages that use the page.php template too. Full page.php content: http://pastebin.com/cbQsKdj6

Comment: Which theme? Post your `functions.php` on pastebin too.

Comment: a bespoke theme i'm developing from scratch but i have some basic templates I usually start with, this is my functions.php - http://pastebin.com/LVqryJ4d
I removed the breadcrumbs and pagination which affected my page content.

Comment: Put only 3 files in your theme: `index.php`, `style.css`, and `page.php` and see whether it's working or not. Then add one by one to see any conflicting file. And `page.php` can be simplest like: `<?php the_post(); the_content(); ?>`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, sorted, re-uploaded my pre-developed functions.php file, in which I had only removed a function for breadcrumbs and one for pagination, but this must have some how affected page content, so anyway this is back, thanks for your time.

Comment: If this is the answer, mark it as the solution so that the question does not show up as unanswered.

Comment: It wont let me accept my own answer until tomorrow, is there a 24 hour restriction on this or something?

Comment: There may be. I don't ask much, I mainly answer.